# Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in microsoft sql server linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, linode

I want to install MSSQL PDO drive to my linode server, so i follow this [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx). Every thing install successfully then also i am getting error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in

My DB server is on azure, and all credentials for connection are correct because same credentials i am using with php and PDO. can anyone help me or guide me?

There is no problem to connect with MySQL and PDO. I am only having problem with SQL-server, although i have install drivers.

I have different problem then mentioned in `marked as duplicate` link

Comment: I have different problem then mentioned in `marked as duplicate` link

Comment: you have the same problem, another driver.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've install the driver, configure them, and restart my apace server, your link doesn't tell me anything new, i know those thing already.

Comment: Your error message says the opposite. You better stick to it.

Comment: :'( yes you are right,

Comment: the doc you linked to says how to install odbc driver for PHP. But for PDO you need to install [PDO ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)